# RDD output in spark-shell differs from print(RDD) in idea

Tags: rdd, spark-shell

```
    val rddData1 = sc.makeRDD(1 to 10, 2)
    println(rddData1.glom.collect)
```

code in idea or spark-shell will output [[I@34a0ef00

but `rddData1.glom.collect` in spark-shell will output Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))

how do i can get Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) in idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .setAppName("myAppName")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rddData1 = sc.makeRDD(1 to 10,2)
println(java.util.Arrays.toString( rddData1.collect()))
// output [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
// 结束任务
sc.stop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to the community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who may not be familiar with the syntax. Further, it can help reduce the need for follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[*]")
  .setAppName("myAppName")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rddData1 = sc.makeRDD(1 to 10,2)
val rddData2 = sc.makeRDD(20 to 25,2)
println(rddData1.glom().collect())
println(java.util.Arrays.deepToString( rddData1.glom().collect().map(_.asInstanceOf[Object])))
// output [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]]
// 结束任务
sc.stop()
```

Comment: For those unfamiliar with Java, this is a bit awkward.